# Importing 3 million records from csv to oracle DB table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-import-wizard

I am trying to import 3 million rows from a csv file to DB table using sql developer import wizard, but getting below error every time when it reaches 12k rows .
When I tried importing only 100 rows from the same file, it inserted successfully. Please help me with the error.

error screenshot:
[image]

File screenshot:

[image]

Comment: the database is killing your session or network connection...do you have an oracle client on your machine? We could setup a sqlldr scenario and it would probably load much faster

Comment: @thatjeffsmith  I tried creating external table and it worked. This will server my purpose. Thanks.